# jQuery UI draggable on form elements

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have an element with some form elements in it:

```
<div id="draggable">
    <button>Drag this</button>
</div>​
```

I make it draggable with jQuery UI:

```
$('#draggable').draggable();​
```

And the form element takes up most of the space in the draggable element:

```
#draggable {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #efe;
    padding: 10px;
}
#draggable button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    border: none;
}​
```

I can click on the div and drag it around, but if I am clicking within the form element and try to drag, nothing happens. Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/ACQrg/

I have also tried specifying a `handle` parameter of `'button'`:

```
$('#draggable').draggable({ handle: 'button' });​
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/ACQrg/1/

I have also tried to pass the mousedown event through to the draggable element:

```
$('#draggable').draggable()
    .find('button').mousedown(function (e) {
        $('#draggable').trigger(e);
     });
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/ACQrg/4/

**Is there a way to make draggable elements draggable by form elements they contain?**

Comment: I had a similar problem, and what I did is add another div on "top" of the form element and use it as handle.

Comment: @CharlesOvando were the form elements still clickable?

Comment: Any updates on this question?

Comment: I need this too. I tried making the elements disabled and that helps thwart the clicks, but still not draggable. The only solution I have found that works is to make a nearly transparent png overlay for the form element. Of course, you have to remove that later when you want to use the element.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because the button is catching the click events and not bubbling them up. Try using a different inner element, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/ACQrg/3/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand this is happening because I am using a form element, and I would like to resolve this without changing my form element to a different type.

Answer (score 0):

This may be similar to Tsachi's answer, but what I ended up doing was creating my original container div that contains two divs, one for my input box and one for my button. This drags around nicely. Then, later when a user is using my system, I am not in the editor and so when they click on the object, I use jquery to replace the divs with input box and button code. (I am asking the user to input their email and click submit)

So it looks like this in my editor mode:

```
<div id="holder">
    <div class="inputelem">Enter Email</div>
    <div class="buttonelem">Submit</div>
</div>
```

Then, drag that as desired. On runtime, I do this:

```
$('#holder').html('<input class="inputelem" type="text" name="email"><input class="buttonelem" type="submit" value="submit">');
```

The only trick is to make sure that the class you define for inputelem and buttonelem look the same on a div as they do on a form element. Kind of a pain, but it works.